# Spring Data Cassandra throws Query timed out after PT2S after two inserts in the DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

Two myRepository.save(myObject) requests are passing just fine but starting with the 3rd one it is failing with the following error although I'm saving (updating) the same object

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: SessionCallback; CQL [INSERT INTO ...]; Query timed out after PT2S; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:160)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraAccessor.translate(CassandraAccessor.java:422)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.translateException(CqlTemplate.java:764)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:136)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
...
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException.copy(DriverTimeoutException.java:34)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:54)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate$StatementCallback.doInSession(CassandraTemplate.java:974)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate$StatementCallback.doInSession(CassandraTemplate.java:960)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:134)
... 128 common frames omitted
```

I tried to increase request timeout but it still fails even after it:

```
spring.data.cassandra.request.timeout=15s
```

There is no additional configuration except for custom converter.
Making the same inserts via cqlsh works fine.

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Dependencies:

1. org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:3.1.2
2. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra:2.4.1
3. com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.9.0

Comment: sprint-data-cassandra depends on the `com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.9.0`, so `cassandra-driver-core` isn't used